# How to list tables where data was inserted deleted or updated in last week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql server 2008 databases, I would like to know which tables was updated last week i.e. tables which has new rows, updated existing rows or which rows are deleted.

Is there any way to do this for existing database.

Comment: Track Data Changes (SQL Server) for SQL server 2008 ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: [Comparing Change Data Capture and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      [db_name] = d.name
    , [table_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , s.last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
JOIN sys.databases d ON s.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON s.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
    AND s.last_user_update IS NOT NULL
    AND s.last_user_update BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: +1 This is good until you don't need user, operation and last value before changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500244%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). It's a good way to keep track of your change on the DB. You have to enable the feature on one or more DBs, then on one or more table (it's a Table feature, so you will do it for every table you need).

---

**Enable CDC on database.**

Let's assume we want to enable CDC for AdventureWorks database. We must run the following SP to be sure this feature will work:

```
USE AdventureWorks 
GO 
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db 
GO
```

As result, we'll find a new schema called *cdc* and several tables automatically added:

- **cdc.captured_columns** – This table returns result for list of captured column.
- **cdc.change_tables** – This table returns list of all the tables which are enabled for capture.
- **cdc.ddl_history** – This table contains history of all the DDL changes since capture data enabled.
- **cdc.index_columns** – This table contains indexes associated with change table.
- **cdc.lsn_time_mapping** – This table maps LSN number and time.

---

**Enable CDC on table.**

After having enabled CDC on desired DB(s) it's time to check if there are tables with this feature on:

```
USE AdventureWorks 
GO 
SELECT [name], is_tracked_by_cdc  
FROM sys.tables 
GO
```

If not, we can enable the changes capture for HumanResources.Shift table with the following procedure:

```
USE AdventureWorks 
GO 
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 
@source_schema = N'HumanResources', 
@source_name   = N'Shift', 
@role_name     = NULL 
GO
```

Be sure you *SQL Agent* is up and running because it will create a job (cdc.AdventureWorks_capture probably) to catch the modifications.
If all procedures are correctly executed we'll find a new table called cdc.HumanResources_Shift_CT, among the system tables, containing all the HumanResources.Shift changes.

**Note**: be careful with @role_name parameter, it specifies database infos access.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find out this info by default unless you already have some auditing system installed.

Only option, assuming your database is in full recovery mode, is to read transaction log and try get info from there.

You can try reading transaction log using sql server functions DBCC LOG and fn_dblog or using third party tools such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As commented by others, Change Data Capture and Change Tracking would be the ideal solutions if you have implemented them. If you have not, then here is a quick way, which will give you info partially:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS Object, last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( <YourDBName>)
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(<YourTableName>)
```

This will tell you what tables were updated when, but may not really serve your purpose, if you are faced with a whodunnit scenario. Also, it will only give you the latest updated timestamp, meaning, if someone updated last week and some one else updated yesterday, you will not see the last week update details.

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It will provide last updated date for each table in database.

```
USE database_name

GO


SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

GO
```

For more reference click [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/)